# SqlKata query returns 2 sets of columns

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlkata

Using this query ...

```
Dim compiler = New SqlServerCompiler()
Dim db = New QueryFactory(conn, compiler)

Dim  objFind = db.Query(table) _
        .WhereContains(field1, term1) _
        .OrderByDesc("Start_Date") _
        .Select("sid", "Start_Date", "Subject", "Comment", "isDeleted") _
         .Get()
```

Returns same columns twice, but correct number of rows to my datagrid.
Called by a button click on a windows form with just the button and the datagrid.
Data is correct, just the double columns.

On VS2022, latest SqlKata (at net2 standard)

Thoughts?

I tried this as well

```
Dim objAll = db.Query(table).Get()
```

it also return double columns

Using SQL Express

Comment: It's far more likely that the UI code displays columns twice. Perhaps the (unspecified) grid already contained data or columns ? At the very least check what query is actually sent to the database. Check the actual contents of `objFind` in the debugger, or by looping over the results and writing each item to the console. *Please* don't use a type prefix. Hungarian notation is considered bad practice since the 1990s. Everything is an object in .NET and unless your query returns a single item, you have a list of somethings. Use meaningful names like `books` or `subjects`

Comment: You can set up [logging](https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/logging) in the QueryFactory to see the generated query.

Comment: This query works just fine. I was able to see each record and correct # of columns were present BEFORE  loading the DataGridView to a datasource in my test app. Thanks for your reply. This was my first post to StackOverFlow. Also you need to check with JetBrains on the Hungarian notation, Resharper still reomends it. Thanks for your feedback, it was very helpful

Comment: No, Jetbrains definitely doesn't recommend it, at least not in C#. The rule set you use may have been based on rules used for VBScript though. The tooling for VB is *very* weak, no matter the vendor. Developers simply don't use VB. And the tools are made from developers, most of whom last used VB in the early 2000s. Even Microsoft gave up on VB.NET after 1-2 decades of trying to provide equal support to C# and VB.